# When is it advantageous to define virtual memory smaller than physical memory?

Tags: virtual-memory

Generally as we know virtual memory is larger than physical memory.But when is it advantageous to define virtual memory smaller than physical memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have pointer-heavy code, you can save memory by choosing a smaller address space. For example, a pointer on a 32-bit platform occupies 4 bytes versus 8 bytes on 64-bit. The same goes for integer types like `size_t`.

This only works and makes sense if:

- Your code/application/server uses multiple processes and all processes together need more memory than the amount of virtual memory (otherwise you wouldn't need more physical than virtual memory).
- Your platform supports more physical than virtual memory (for example, Intel PAE).
- The smaller amount of virtual memory is enough for each single process.

Comment: I also read that in a VM ,lesser virtual memory is advantageous,can you elaborate?

Comment: @SukalyanSen Welcome to StackOverflow! This site works a bit different than other forums. Please use the "Ask Question" button to ask new questions.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a large server system supporting multiple users. You don't want users to hog memory, so you restrict the size of the logical (virtual) address space by limiting page table size.